# Docker is not working in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a new on the docker. I installed docker toolbox in my machine.When I add the docker support in VS2017 then I got the following error:

Unable to switch Docker to use Windows containers. Please restart Docker and ensure that Windows containers are selected.
Unable to run 'dockercli'. Verify that Docker for Windows is installed and running locally. For troubleshooting, please review http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting.

Could you let me know how i solve the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Follow the link in the error message, you can browse lots of report issues, https://github.com/microsoft/dockertools/issues

Answer (score 0):

> I installed docker toolbox in my machine

Docker toolbox is for legacy OS which doesn't meet minimal system requirement for Docker. It doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017.

If you want to develop .NET application inside docker container in Visual Studio 2017, you need to install [Docker Community Edition (CE)](https://www.docker.com/community-edition#/download).

After installing, you select the prefer OS in docker daemon and then pick the corresponding OS in Visual Studio.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Step 0:** Run Docker locally - (in windows container mode)

**Step 1:** Create a new project with the following option:

[image: Create new project with Docker support]

**Step 2:** Modify your dockerfile to look like following (The two lines
 **FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS base** are the changes made to the default dockerfile created by the visual studio 2017 template)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

**Step 3:** Run the project - Ctrl F5. You would be asked to add a certificate as shown below.Accept and click on YES. Let the certificate be installed locally.

[image]

**Step 4:** I can see the container running:

[image]